# Get Wordpress Settings Email

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im trying to get the email stored udner 'settings' in wordpress. I know there was an old function for this: `get_settings` but this is [depreciated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_settings). I can't find a replacement - is there a reason for this? What is the best practice method for returning the settings email in wordpress?

Comment: Check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Generally, I would but wp stack has few users and technical questions like this have a bad habit of never getting answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [`get_settings()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_settings), use [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Example:

```
$email = get_option('admin_email');
```